# ArgumentNullException caused by DataAnnotations validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model which is binded to a view. I'm trying to add RegEx attribute to certain input fields. If I do that it gives me this:

```
EventName="MessageEvent" Message="Unhandled ArgumentNullException in Papaya.Web.Controllers.CompanyController Update
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
at
at  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext.set_DisplayName(String value)
```

If the RegularExpresion attribute is not set, it works fine. Here is the model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Company_Resources.RequiredName), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Company_Resources))]
[RegularExpression(Helpers.InputValidationStringLetters, ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Common_Resources.emsgInputValidationStringLetters), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Common_Resources))]
[Display(Name = nameof(Company_Resources.NameLbl), ResourceType = typeof(Company_Resources))]
public virtual string Name { get; set; }

[CorporateIdentityNumber(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Customer_Resources.vmsgInvalidCorporateIdentityNumber), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Customer_Resources))]
    [RegularExpression(Helpers.InputValidationStringNumbers, ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Common_Resources.emsgInputValidationStringNumbers), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Common_Resources))]
    [Display(Name = nameof(Company_Resources.CompanyRegSocialSecurityNoLbl), ResourceType = typeof(Company_Resources))]
    public virtual string CompanyRegSocialSecurityNo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = nameof(Company_Resources.lblAddress1), ResourceType = typeof(Company_Resources))]
   [RegularExpression(Helpers.InputValidationStringLettersNumbersDots, ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Common_Resources.emsgInputValidationStringLettersNumbersDots), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Common_Resources))]
     public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = nameof(Company_Resources.lblAddress2), ResourceType = typeof(Company_Resources))]
    [RegularExpression(Helpers.InputValidationStringLettersNumbersDots, ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Common_Resources.emsgInputValidationStringLettersNumbersDots), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Common_Resources))]
    public virtual string Address2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = nameof(Company_Resources.ZipCodeLbl), ResourceType = typeof(Company_Resources))]
    [RegularExpression(Helpers.InputValidationStringNumbers, ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Common_Resources.emsgInputValidationStringNumbers), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Common_Resources))]
    public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = nameof(Company_Resources.CityLbl), ResourceType = typeof(Company_Resources))]
    [RegularExpression(Helpers.InputValidationStringLetters, ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Common_Resources.emsgInputValidationStringLetters), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Common_Resources))]
    public virtual string City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = nameof(Company_Resources.PhoneLbl), ResourceType = typeof(Company_Resources))]
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
```

Am I missing something?

Edit:
On one display value I used a string from the resources, which was null, therefore the error. Thanks guys!

Comment: Although this is not my specialty I will share my knowledge with you. What this Argument Null Exception is, is saying that it has a value which is null and that should not be null for the function to work. So obviously you are not setting that variable to something before passing it to the function. It tells you the place where the null argument exception occurs that means the actual function where it occurs being : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext.set_DisplayName(String value). It tells you that the string Value is null. No where in your code do I see set_DisplayName!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below regular expression for allow only letters:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
     string TextBoxData {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

and apply like below:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TextBoxData)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TextBoxData )
```